# Is it possible to have multiple terminal states with a WF state machine?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4.5

I'm just learning about using state machines in WF. I'm wondering if I can have multiple exit states?  The use case would be a single entry state which would end up in one of multiple exit (terminal/final) states. E.g. lets say the object is an order. The entry state would be 'Pending' but it could end up in one of two states (after some processing): 'Shipped' or 'Canceled'. Is this possible or does a state machine have to have one terminal state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just doing an experiment and WF does in fact support multiple terminal states (at least 4.5 does).  I had a state machine setup with a single entry state (Opened), then it transitioned to three final states (Closed, Faulted, Canceled). It worked great.